# Calculating damage from a flood at the village level in percentage

Tags: arcgis-desktop, area

[image]I am using ArcGIS for my analysis. I want to calculate the damage from a flood at the village level in terms of percentage area damaged.

I have done the following steps.

1. My village file is in point shape ad I have overlayed it with a district-level polygon in order to identify it (by using `"Join Relates"` option, the resulting output is in point shape).
2. I have flood polygon, I have used the output at step 1 for intersection with flood polygon, I get the results (the resulting output is point shape).

Now I want the guidance for area calculation given output file is point shape. How can I do that?

Comment: When you want an area metric, intersection between a point and polygon doesn't make much sense. Are your points inside the flood polygons? A screenshot of the three layers would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot @kowalski, the image is added in the edited version of original question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't see how you can calculate areas using point features. Do they have any attributes regarding the areas of the villages and the flood percentage or similar?

Comment: If you just have points representing locations of individual villages, all you could say is N% of villages had some level of flooding, i.e if you have 20 villages and 10 of those points intersect the flood polygon, you can say 50% of villages flooded.